# PIC Embedded C printf Corrupted Output - Very odd

Tags: c, embedded, printf, uart, pic

I have a 69 element array `MBRespon[i]` of hex data which I'm sending out of two USARTs on a PIC18F46K40. The first USART loops through the data and transmits everything fine, and when that's done the code goes through a 2nd loop where it prints the formatted data out of the 2nd UART using:

```
printf("   Byte %02i : 0x%02x \r\n", i, MBRespon[i]);
```

At first it looks like the data is being printed out fine, however upon closer inspection around the 57th byte it sends the wrong thing. At first I thought this might have been a EUSART2_TX_BUFFER_SIZE issue, and indeed changing the buffer sizes does have a impact; more gets corrupt when it's anything different than 32.

```
#define EUSART2_TX_BUFFER_SIZE 32   // 32 Works (Sort of)
#define EUSART2_RX_BUFFER_SIZE 32   // 32 Works (Sort of)
```

If i reduce the number of elements in the array to 58 or less it's fine, anything more and it's corrupt.

My code:

```
  void PrintModRespon(){

    int i=0;
    
    printf("Modbus Response Count %i:\r\n",MBResCnt);
    while(!EUSART2_is_tx_ready());      // Hold the program until TX is ready
    
    for(i=0; i< MBResCnt ; i++ ){
        while(!EUSART2_is_tx_ready()); // Hold the program until TX is ready

        printf("   Byte %02i : 0x%02x \r\n", i, MBRespon[i]); 
   
        while(!EUSART2_is_tx_done());   // Hold until done.

    }
    
    while(!EUSART2_is_tx_ready());      // Hold the program until TX is ready
    printf("\r\n\n");
    while(!EUSART2_is_tx_done());
     
}
```

I added in  `while(!EUSART2_is_tx_ready());`  and  `while(!EUSART2_is_tx_done());`  as I thought it may be the UART wasn't ready/busy, but they didn't make any difference.

UART1 Output (The good one):

```
 06 03 40 00 01 00 02 00 03 ....etc.... 00 1a 00 1b 00 1c 00 1d 00 1e 00 1f 00 20 5c 30
```

UART2 Output (The bad one):

```
Modbus Response Count 69:
   Byte 00 : 0x06
   Byte 01 : 0x03
   Byte 02 : 0x40
   Byte 03 : 0x00
   Byte 04 : 0x01
   Byte 05 : 0x00
   Byte 06 : 0x02
   Byte 07 : 0x00
   Byte 08 : 0x03
```

..etc...

```
   Byte 53 : 0x00
   Byte 54 : 0x1a
   Byte 55 : 0x00
   Byte 56 : 0x1b
   Byte 57 : 0x14    // <-- This is NOT in the array!
   Byte 58 : 0x1c
   Byte 59 : 0x00
   Byte 60 : 0x1d
   Byte 61 : 0x00
   Byte 62 : 0x1e
   Byte 63 : 0x00
   Byte 64 : 0x1f
   Byte 65 : 0x00
   Byte 66 : 0x20
   Byte 67 : 0x5c
   Byte 68 : 0x30
```

Oddly, as another test, I changed the printf function to:

```
printf("   Byte %02i : 0x%02x \r\n", i, 0x00 +i);
```

I.E Not using the array of data, and it output 69x incremented values fine! Which suggests it's not a UART buffer/timing issue?

```
Modbus Response Count 69:
   Byte 00 : 0x00
   Byte 01 : 0x01
   Byte 02 : 0x02
 
...etc.

   Byte 51 : 0x33
   Byte 52 : 0x34
   Byte 53 : 0x35
   Byte 54 : 0x36
   Byte 55 : 0x37
   Byte 56 : 0x38
   Byte 57 : 0x39
   Byte 58 : 0x3a
   Byte 59 : 0x3b
   Byte 60 : 0x3c
   Byte 61 : 0x3d
   Byte 62 : 0x3e
   Byte 63 : 0x3f
   Byte 64 : 0x40
   Byte 65 : 0x41
   Byte 66 : 0x42
   Byte 67 : 0x43
   Byte 68 : 0x44
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this for days now!

Comment: where is the send part? did you check padding?

Comment: The printf in the PrintModRespon function. I've edied the post to space it out so easier to see. I'm not sure what you mean by checking padding?

Comment: From your description of the problem it seems that another thread/process changes the array. The code you show looks innocent. Do you have interrupts running that write into the array? Sending bytes over a UART takes a lot of time. What baudrate do you use? And what parameters, 8-n-1?

Comment: usually, compiler adds extra space at the end (or inside) the strucures to keep memory accesses aligned. This cause structures to hold "more" data than expected and send(data, sizeof(my_struct) ) to send "too many" bytes as the padding is sent as well.

Comment: @thebusybee hhhmm, no intterupts, It's running at 19200, 8 bits, 1 stop, parity none. It was 9600 baud originally and I thought speeding it up might empty the UART out faster but again made no difference and I've just let it at 19200 for now.

Comment: OK, strange. -- 20 characters per line @19200 8n1 take 20 * 10 (bits/character) / 19200 = 10,4ms. 58 lines are sent after about 600ms. Does this duration ring a bell? -- How is `MBRespon` defined?

Comment: @thebusybee So your last statement about "How is the array being defined?" got me tinkering. It was `unsigned int MBRespon[32]` however I just changed it to `unsigned char MBRespon[32]` and now it works!!! I'm getting a ton of warnings about incompatible data types though, hopefully I can fix them! No idea why that would cause it, but at least it works!

Comment: Well, 69 elements out of a 32-element array... What did you learn? Raise the warning level to the maximum and massage your code until no error or warning is left. ;-) Voting to close because of [PEBKAS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK).

Comment: Inspect the memory in your debugger to determine whether the array has been corrupted by some previous operation or if it is modified in the output.  Is it always the same location and same change?  When you used `unsigned int` is the MSB zero?  Does it work if you `printf("   Byte %02i : 0x%02x \r\n", i, MBRespon[i] & 0x00FF ); `?

Answer (score -1):

This is very likely a padding issue since the first element of your structure has an odd number of bytes.

When defining structures, the compiler will create one-byte padding between elements if they do not fall on the default alignment of the processor. A 16-bit processor will want most things aligned on word boundaries (i.e. even addresses), including byte arrays (e.g. arrays of char). The exception is elements that only occupy one byte.

On a 16-bit Microchip MPU, if you try to access word or dword data on odd address, it will cause a memory fault. The compiler is trying to keep this from happening.

If your structure only contains byte-sized elements (char, uint8_t, etc.), or arrays of the same, you can force byte alignment by adding the qualifier `__attribute__((packed))` to the structure declaration. This can be dangerous because you may end up with elements having odd addresses. This is OK as long as the odd-addressed elements are only accessed as bytes (e.g. a char array), but proceed with caution.

Comment: Pic18 is 8 bits and

Comment: Ok, my error, but unworthy of a downvote. The compiler using word alignment remains the issue, and packing the structure will get rid of the padding byte.

Comment: @EBlake, Perhaps you should delete your answer because it's not relevant for a controller like the PIC18F46K40 with an 8-bit data path. Byte padding does not occur in the XC8 compiler data structures.